# Excel 2013 VBA Worksheet_Change merged cell with formula

Tags: excel, vba, merge, sum, formula

Ok, I've been searching around the site and cannot find an answer. I have a 2 sheet workbook. I have a merged cell of about 14 individual cells which has a SUM formula of other cells all on the same worksheet. I am trying to get the WorkSheet_Change function to recognize when the value changes in my SUM'ed merged cell and modify a shape in a different sheet. I've named the merged cells with the SUM function "AGILITY", but it doesn't work if I use the actual range of cells O35:U36 either. Any assistance is appreciated!

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Target.Address = "AGILITY" Then
    If Target.Value = 0 Then
        Worksheets("Character").Shapes("Oval 5").Fill.ForeColor.RGB = vbBlack
        Worksheets("Character").Shapes("Oval 16").Fill.ForeColor.RGB = vbWhite
        Worksheets("Character").Shapes("Oval 17").Fill.ForeColor.RGB = vbWhite
        Worksheets("Character").Shapes("Oval 18").Fill.ForeColor.RGB = vbWhite
        Worksheets("Character").Shapes("Oval 19").Fill.ForeColor.RGB = vbWhite
    ElseIf Target.Value = 1 Then
        Worksheets("Character").Shapes("Oval 5").Fill.ForeColor.RGB = vbWhite
        Worksheets("Character").Shapes("Oval 16").Fill.ForeColor.RGB = vbBlack
        Worksheets("Character").Shapes("Oval 17").Fill.ForeColor.RGB = vbWhite
        Worksheets("Character").Shapes("Oval 18").Fill.ForeColor.RGB = vbWhite
        Worksheets("Character").Shapes("Oval 19").Fill.ForeColor.RGB = vbWhite
    ElseIf Target.Value = 2 Then
        Worksheets("Character").Shapes("Oval 5").Fill.ForeColor.RGB = vbWhite
        Worksheets("Character").Shapes("Oval 16").Fill.ForeColor.RGB = vbWhite
        Worksheets("Character").Shapes("Oval 17").Fill.ForeColor.RGB = vbBlack
        Worksheets("Character").Shapes("Oval 18").Fill.ForeColor.RGB = vbWhite
        Worksheets("Character").Shapes("Oval 19").Fill.ForeColor.RGB = vbWhite
    ElseIf Target.Value = 3 Then
        Worksheets("Character").Shapes("Oval 5").Fill.ForeColor.RGB = vbWhite
        Worksheets("Character").Shapes("Oval 16").Fill.ForeColor.RGB = vbWhite
        Worksheets("Character").Shapes("Oval 17").Fill.ForeColor.RGB = vbWhite
        Worksheets("Character").Shapes("Oval 18").Fill.ForeColor.RGB = vbBlack
        Worksheets("Character").Shapes("Oval 19").Fill.ForeColor.RGB = vbWhite
    ElseIf Target.Value = 4 Then
        Worksheets("Character").Shapes("Oval 5").Fill.ForeColor.RGB = vbWhite
        Worksheets("Character").Shapes("Oval 16").Fill.ForeColor.RGB = vbWhite
        Worksheets("Character").Shapes("Oval 17").Fill.ForeColor.RGB = vbWhite
        Worksheets("Character").Shapes("Oval 18").Fill.ForeColor.RGB = vbWhite
        Worksheets("Character").Shapes("Oval 19").Fill.ForeColor.RGB = vbBlack
    Else
        Worksheets("Character").Shapes("Oval 5").Fill.ForeColor.RGB = vbWhite
        Worksheets("Character").Shapes("Oval 16").Fill.ForeColor.RGB = vbWhite
        Worksheets("Character").Shapes("Oval 17").Fill.ForeColor.RGB = vbWhite
        Worksheets("Character").Shapes("Oval 18").Fill.ForeColor.RGB = vbWhite
        Worksheets("Character").Shapes("Oval 19").Fill.ForeColor.RGB = vbWhite
    End If
End If End Sub
```

Comment: `if Not Intersect(Target,Range("AGILITY")) is nothing then`

Comment: Following @ScottCraner comment above, replace your multiple `ElseIf Target.Value` with `Select Case Target.Value`. and use also `With Worksheets("Character")` to clean-up your code a little.

Comment: @ScottCraner - not sure what you are trying to get me to accomplish with that, but I added it just under the "Private Sub" line "If Not Intersect(Target, Range("AGILITY")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub". It still doesn't work. I changed from "Not Intersect" to simply "Intersect" and still doesn't work. I got it working when everything was on the same sheet, but not when I moved it. I have double checked all the "names" and they are correct.

Comment: It should replace your first If staetment.

Comment: Ok, obviously I am a total noob, so forgive my ignorance. I made your changes Scott and Shai, I think I made your changes as well, but what is "With Worksheets"

`code Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("AGILITY")) Is Nothing Then
        Select Case Target.Value = "0"
            Worksheets("Character").Shapes("Oval 5").Fill.ForeColor.RGB = vbBlack`

Comment: `"0"` should only be `0`

Comment: Ok, here is my code now...still doesn't work. I shortened it of course. No errors. 
`Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("AGILITY")) Is Nothing Then
        Select Case Target.Value
            Case 0
                Worksheets("Character").Shapes("Oval 5").Fill.ForeColor.RGB = vbBlack    
        End Select
    End If
End Sub `

Comment: Don't post code in comments

Comment: The Worksheet_Change does not get triggered on a change to a calculated (i.e. formula) cell.

Comment: @Jeeped - apologies for posting code, wasn't sure what to do. So how does one accomplish the change if Worksheet_Change does work on calculated cells?

Comment: @all - I finally got it working using Worksheet_Calculate and then setting some variables and using IsNumeric with an IF and iterating though it with Select Case.